# how to put single quotes and a coma to a string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to put singles quotes with comma at the end of the line but can't think how i can achieve this. So far i am only able to put single quote with comma at the end , but i would like put put single quote at the beginning of the line as well. Can somebody please help

I would like to achieve 'test1',
but at the moment i can only do test1',

```
#Define Variables
$a = 'P:\Powershell practice\Movefolder\LD.txt'
$b = get-content $a

#Define Functions
function append-text { 
 process{
 foreach-object {$_ + "',"}
} 
}

#Process Code
$b | append-text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
function append-text { 
process{
foreach-object {"'" + $_ + "',"}
} 
}
```